# Bind JSON webservice in list View

Tags: json, web-services, c#-4.0, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to bind the json webservice into my list view adapter. I am getting error. Need to bind those values in the List View

```
 [Activity(Label = "ListView", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        private ListView mListView;

        public virtual IListAdapter ListAdapter { get; set; }
        private List<RootObject> mUsers;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            mListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);

            var url = "https://www.yellowbox.com.sg/index.php?route=api/app/getusers";

            // Syncronious Consumption

            var syncClient = new WebClient();

            var content = syncClient.DownloadString(url);

            var TEST = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <RootObject>(content);
            // getting null values in "TEST"
            //mUsers =????
            ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<RootObject>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, mUsers);
             mListView.Adapter = ListAdapter;
        }
```

My class:

public class RootObject
    {

```
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string total_deliveries { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is your JSON? are you sure your content is not empty before deserialisation?

Comment: if you're getting an error, it's generally helpful if you tell us what the ERROR MESSAGE IS!

Comment: My content is not empty have got value.